# Mix lifetimes of references in Vec

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime

I am attempting to generate a `Vec<&'b Color>` from `Vec<&'a Color>`:

```
impl <'a> Canvas<'a> {
    pub fn modify<'b>(&self, update: Update) -> Canvas<'b> {
        let x  = update.x;
        let y  = update.y;
        let colors: Vec<&'b Color> = self.colors.iter().enumerate().map(move |(index, color)| {
                if index == self.width * y + x { update.color } else { color }
            })
            .collect();
        Canvas { width: self.width, height: self.height, colors: colors }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/canvas.rs:51:50
   |
51 |         let colors: Vec<&'b Color> = self.colors.iter().enumerate().map(move |(index, color)| {
   |                                                  ^^^^
```

How can I create a `Vec` of colors, all but one with lifetime `'a`, and the remaining with lifetime `'b`?

If needed, the relevant definitions are as follows:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Color {
    White,
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green,
    Purple,
    Orange
}

pub struct Update<'a> {
    color: &'a Color,
    x: usize,
    y: usize
}

pub struct Canvas<'a> {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    colors: Vec<&'a Color>
}
```

Comment: Why you need a `&'a Color` anyway? Using `Color` directly should be much more efficient and easier ;).

Comment: Is there a way to use `Color` directly without cloning each `Color` into the new `Vec`, other than using mutability?

Comment: `Color` should derive Copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I create a `Vec` of colors, all but one with lifetime `'a`, and the remaining with lifetime `'b`?

You *cannot*. Lifetimes are generics, and just like it doesn't make sense to have "a `Vec<T>`, all but one of `T` is the type `String`, and the remaining `T` is the type `bool`", it doesn't make sense to do so with lifetimes.

What you can do is unify the lifetimes:

```
impl<'a> Canvas<'a> {
    pub fn modify(&self, update: Update<'a>) -> Canvas<'a> {
        let x = update.x;
        let y = update.y;
        let colors = self.colors
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(move |(index, color)| if index == self.width * y + x {
                     update.color
                 } else {
                     color
                 })
            .collect();
        Canvas {
            width: self.width,
            height: self.height,
            colors: colors,
        }
    }
}
```

Here, we've said that the `update.color` lifetime and the lifetime of the contained references have an intersection, and that's what the lifetime of the result will be.

---

Another common solution for a heterogenous collection of a fixed set of types is to introduce an enum with variants for each one:

```
pub enum Thing<'a, 'b>  {
    A(&'a Color),
    B(&'b Color),
}

impl<'a> Canvas<'a> {
    pub fn modify<'b>(&self, update: Update<'b>) -> Vec<Thing<'a, 'b>> {
        let x = update.x;
        let y = update.y;
        self.colors
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(move |(index, color)| if index == self.width * y + x {
                     Thing::B(update.color)
                 } else {
                     Thing::A(color)
                 })
            .collect()
    }
}
```